# How to modify some characters in an array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have this variable :

> terms2 =  ['5*x^4', '4*x^3', '2/x^2']

I neew to make some changes when '/' appears and after that terms2 should be:

> terms2 = ['5*x^4', '4*x^3', '2*x^-2']

I've been shearching for a way to do this for some days, thanks.

Comment: Is `a*x^b` the general format of the terms? A simple fix would be to iterate through the list and replace each string where `/x^` occurs with `*x^-`

Comment: simply do `terms2 = [x.replace('/x^', '*x^-') for x in terms2]`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri What about the minus sign?

Comment: @ChristianDean Well, that went unnoticed earlier :P

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri thank you a lot, i finally finish my project !